# How do I delete my own tweets in TweetDeck v1.0?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

How do I delete my own tweets in the new (v1.0) TweetDeck?

It was pretty clear how to do this in the former Adobe AIR application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the Right most button below tweet.

[image]

Comment: Oh, it was so simple (and so unobvious)! Thank you